# Finding entity by unique name, create if not found , fill it and then save. Twice saved by two transactions because of concurrency

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, transactions, database-deadlocks

I've stumbled upon a problem, which we could not solve via locking strategies and transaction isolation.  We have an application, which pushes message to an active MQ. We have a constant listener for this queue.

We have a state report within this message, which should be updated or created (if not there). The report is queried by a unique name ('applicationId'), but this is not a primary key, nor is there a unique constraint on it.

The report is afterwards filled /updated and saved to the database.

I cannot immediately save/persist the entity, when no entity is found and fill the created entity when no matching report is found. I must stick to saving the report at the end of filling the report with data. This is because the underlying table will be fetched every 5 min. or so by an external system and then be deleted.

The problem is: I have 3 incoming messages for the same applicationId within a few milliseconds. After the first two incoming messages, there are 2 reports with the same applicationId in the db and the 3rd update request fails because the find query expects a single result

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
    @Override
    public Report saveReportinDB(APPLICATION application)
    {
        // check if already exists by key applicationId
        Report report =  this.reportRepository.findOneByApplicationID(application.getAppId());

        if (report == null)
        {
            report = new Report();
        }  

       /*this takes longer, so the next application is comming 
         in and does not find a report with the same applicationId
         within the db because the report which is filled 
         at the moment is not yet persisted*/

        fillReportWithData(application, report);

        report = ReportRepository.save(report);
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: And if you check if there is a report just before saving?

Comment: You can read more about Distributed Locks using Redis
https://www.google.at/search?q=java+lock+distributed+systems&ie=UTF-8&oe=

Comment: @Ralf Renz I thought about that too , but that does not solve the problem if at the moment of finding a save happens and the table may be locked at them moment too so find delivers nothing ....

Comment: which one do you want to update, the first one or the second one.

Comment: You absolutely cannot solve this without coordination between the two 'servers'. Your only degree of freedom is how the coordination is effected - through the database, through a distributed lock manager, or through some other mechanism.

Comment: @user13784117 Unfortunately I guess you are right...we solved it throug Active MQ message groups which assures that the messages are only processed after the previous one is processed without failures. But I was wondering if there really is no other way....

Comment: If this happens rarely enough, then perhaps you can make the 'save' fail by some uniqueness constraint on application id, then you discard the report,  loop back and redo it on the existing record.  Wasted work, sure, but it's rare, right?

Comment: @user13784117 thanks for the comment, we solved it already through activemq...unfortunately it is not rare. happens around 100 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

The code that runs between 'find whether app id is used yet' and 'finish the work to persist the app id' needs to be atomic, i.e., inside a lock that is somewhere common to both servers.

Personally, I'd explore making the database serve that function (by writing the app record in a 'pending' state), but if you can't do that, a separate lock record, keyed on app id, seems appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, we tried and ran into deadlocks and cannot aqcuire lock exception .. :(

Comment: Cannot acquire lock is not deadlock assuming one of them is progressing. I assume only one of the parallel operations came back with that exception and other one is progressing. So you have handle the exception with retry logic by taking into account of how long an uninterrupted operation takes.

Comment: Deadlock is when you have two parallel txns, `txn1` acquires the lock for  `record1` and wants the lock `record2` while `txn2` acquires the lock for `record2` first and wants the lock for `record1`.